# local file path won't import

Tags: swift, import, local, filepath

I am trying to import the content of a .txt file to a string in my Xcode 9 project using Swift 4. When I use the full path name it imports successfully, current code:

```
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/main/Documents/ClaasPDI/PDIapp/PDIapp/holdMachines.txt")

do
{
    machineString = try String(contentsOf: filePath)

}
catch
{
    print("MACHINE INFORMATION DID NOT IMPORT")
}
```

I want to be able to import the data from the local path so it can be run on other computers besides mine. My swift files and holdMachines.txt are in the same folder PDIapp but when I change the code to:

```
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "holdMachines.txt")
```

it now crashes my app and says it could not access the file.

I also tried it with a / infront of the file name (below) but that also failed.

```
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/holdMachines.txt")
```

How can I change my code to access the file through a local file path?

Comment: You probably need to include the file in your bundle. If it's going to be something that changes over time and more than one person needs access to it, you need to post it on a server where it can be retrieved within the app. If that's the case, you should ensure only the appropriate people can access it.

Comment: Your catch block is not really helpful if you don't print the actual error message. Do `catch{
    print("MACHINE INFORMATION DID NOT IMPORT, error: \(error)")
}` to see the actual error message. However, the most immediate issue clearly is that you are trying to input a local filepath to a method that expects a full filepath. You have to use `let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: relativeTo:)` to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text file in your Xcode project and use the following code to read it into a string:

```
let txtFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "holdMachines", ofType: "txt")
do {
        let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: txtFile!, encoding: .utf8)
} catch let err {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
}
```